# Apache Camel | FTP | Consuming only single file

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel

I am trying to read all the text files in a ftp directory, parse them. If the parsing is successful, then move them to a different directory(not the default one i.e. .done directory) and if the parsing fails then file should remain in the ftp directory. The concept looks simple but then my route only reads a single file from ftp and routes ends itself after fetching one file.

Following is the code:

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

         from(EndPointConstants.DIRECT + GetDriverProductInfo.class.getSimpleName())  
        .pollEnrich(ftp://ingestion_user@10.207.6.42/fantics?password=******&recursive=true)
        .to("file://test/readFile")
```

Is it something related to pollEnrich that its only able to get a single file and the process is not happening recursively?

Answer (score 3):

> If the parsing is successful, then move them to a different directory(not the default one i.e. .done directory)

Use something like this example:

```
.to("file://test/readFile?autoCreate=true&moveFailed=.failed/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}&move=.processed/${date:now:dd-MM-yyyy}/${file:name}")
```

From the Camel Documentation ([FTP/SFTP/FTPS Component](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html)):

> The FTP consumer will by default leave the consumed files untouched on the remote FTP server. You have to configure it explicitly if you want it to delete the files or move them to another location. For example you can use delete=true to delete the files, or use move=.done to move the files into a hidden done sub directory.
>   The regular File consumer is different as it will by default move files to a .camel sub directory. The reason Camel does not do this by default for the FTP consumer is that it may lack permissions by default to be able to move or delete files.

So You can use for example:

```
&noop=false

&move

&delete=false
```

**EDIT:**

I think you should come up with something like this (the following code) as pollEnrich() doesn't suite for this case.

(The following code is highly discouraged to be used as it is rather than an example of use)

```
from("direct:scan")
    .process(new Processor()
    {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
        {
            ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createConsumerTemplate();
            ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
            producerTemplate.setDefaultEndpointUri("file:..");
            producerTemplate.send(consumerTemplate.receive("ftp:.."));
        }
    });
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the resolution but the problem is something else. I want all the files in FTP folder to be consumed by a single route. Currently above code just fetches one file and stops the route. I want to fetch all the files in a single go from FTP and then iterate through the list of files in route. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should consume from ftp then, eg from(ftp), then it polls all the files. pollEnrich is for polling a *single* message.

Comment: as @ClausIbsen said. You might want to use .from(..) and add an aggregation policy http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html . There is also an option for ftp to iterate through the ftp directory.

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen and Bagos but this doesnt solve my problem either. Earlier I was trying to use .from(ftp) but the problem is that in dev env, we are running the route from junits by using ProducerTemplate.sendBody("Test") and configuring uri by pointing to the route. In this case my first from() is the direct: and second is .from(ftp) as shown below. Running this particular route doesnt hit the ftp and body only contains by what its been set in the junit.
Code is in the following comment.
What can be done to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

     from(EndPointConstants.DIRECT + this.getClass().getSimpleName())
        .from("ftp://ingestion_user@10.207.6.42/fantics?password=*******&recursive=true") 
  .to(ProductFTPURLHelper.getPath());
 }